# Cannot import tensorflow in python after source build

Tags: python-2.7, tensorflow

I am trying to install tensorflow with cuda and cudnn on a linux machine. I do not have sudo access, so I am building from source. I followed instructions here: https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#source

I got till the part where we get lots of output:

```
This tutorial iteratively calculates the major eigenvalue of a 2x2 matrix, on GPU.
The last few lines look like this.
000009/000005 lambda = 2.000000 x = [0.894427 -0.447214] y = [1.788854 -0.894427]
000006/000001 lambda = 2.000000 x = [0.894427 -0.447214] y = [1.788854 -0.894427]
```

But after that, when I open python and try to import tensorflow, it says there is no such module.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Also, I do not understand why we are building only the example_trainer in this line: 

bazel build -c opt --config=cuda //tensorflow/cc:tutorials_example_trainer

Shouldn't we build the whole package?

Answer (score 3):

You need to take a few more steps before you can import TensorFlow in a Python shell: just building `//tensorflow/cc:tutorials_example_trainer` does not build any of the Python front-end.

The easiest way to do this from a source installation is to follow the [instructions for building a PIP package from source](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/get_started/os_setup.html#create-the-pip-package-and-install), and then installing it (either globally on your machine, or in a [virtualenv](https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/r0.8/get_started/os_setup.html#virtualenv_installation)).

Comment: The anchor in the link is dead. Here's a new one https://www.tensorflow.org/versions/master/get_started/os_setup.html#create-the-pip-package-and-install  (comment edited)

Comment: Thanks! Fixed them in the answer.